# How do I run phpunit over folders matching a pattern

Tags: phpunit

I have a folder structure like this

```
root_folder
    folder1
      _unittest
   <other files>
folder2
   _unittest
   <other files>
```

Now what I want to do is run phpunit from the root on files found in all the subfolders named _unittest

Can anyone suggest how this can be done (maybe using the xml config file?)

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can indeed use `testsuites` directive in phpunit.xml.dist, but this directive allow you to play with wildcards and target easily subdirectories in one testsuite. For your exampple, you can do it like that:

```
<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="only-unit-test">
        <directory suffix=".php">./*/_unittest/</directory>
    </testsuite>
    <testsuite name="all-test">
        <directory suffix=".php">./</directory>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

phpunit will go through all subfolders and check for testcases in *_unittest* folders. It avoids to have an entry for each folder in your configuration.

Comment: Thanks - I've decided to go with the test suites approach

Comment: Thank u. I've used it too. +1

Answer (score 0):

PHPunit will, when the xml config is set only run files from a given set of directories

```
<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="test-suite">
        <directory suffix=".php">./folder1/_unittest</directory>
        <!-- other listing of directories for tests -->
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

If your `folder2` is at the same level as `root_folder` then you may want to rethink the structure, or place the test configuration in a different directory.

Comment: Ok thanks - Do I have to put an entry for each _unittest folder in the config file - there will be many such folders. I was hoping not to have to do that.

Comment: The usual way these days is to have a single ./tests/ directory in the base of a project, with the tests specific to that project, and mirror the directories and namespaces of the main code with a `Tests\` namespace prefix. While adding more lines of config to the .xml file isn't hard, keeping the tests apart from the code is probably better.